# Class_Weight for Multiclass classification in Neural Network

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, tf.keras

I am working on a Neural Network for Multiclass classification where class labels are -1,0,1.

These class labels imbalanced hence I am using class_weights. And I am getting below error message-

`` Expected `class_weight` to be a dict with keys from 0 to one less than the number of classes ``

Does it mean, I can't use -1 as label?